# Format values with sourceformat

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working code which generates random values from the columns of ADMIN_ARB11 sheet into the cells of the Test-Input_Vorschlag sheet. However there is one problem, the generated values are not in the source format. Can anyone help in changing the code

```
Sub Random_ARB11()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, LB As Long, UB  As Long
Set sh1 = Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag")
Set sh2 = Sheets("ADMIN_ARB11")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For j = 7 To 1000
    LB = 2
    If sh1.Cells(1, j) = "ARB11" Then
        For i = 11 To 382
            UB = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, i - 10).End(xlUp).Row 
            **sh1.Cells(i, j) = sh2.Cells(Int((UB - LB + 1) * Rnd + LB), i - 10).Value**
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Can I change the .Value to .Sourcevalue or something like that which keeps the source format intact?

Answer (score 0):

An easy alternative (though possibly not ideal depending on how much data you are working with) is to use the copy method, which will preserve all formatting.

`sh1.Cells(i,j).Copy Destination:= sh2.Cells(Int((UB - LB + 1) * Rnd + LB),i-10)`